# What does "get in a flap" mean?

Tags: idioms

I came across the passage "My mum would get in a flap...", so I wonder: what does "get in a flap" mean?

I've found that "flap" means, as a noun: 'An excited state of agitation'. Of course, there are other meanings, but I found this one to be the nearest in context. I still can't quite figure out the correct explanation though.

Comment: This uses *get* in the sense "to become or cause to become or act as specified" ([Collins, 5](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get)) and *flap* in the sense you have identified.

Comment: Alternatively, the writer's mum climbed inside a thin, flat, hinged opening on a regular basis...(note to non-native speakers: this is a joke. Please do not take it seriously XD)

Comment: Is that in addition to or in place of the one for the cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To

> **get in a flap**

is to be agitated, worried, or excited (not in a good way) about *something*.
It is a typical BrE expression.

It can have the same meaning as

> **Don't get your knickers in a twist**.

It is the opposite of

> **chill out
>
>   calm down**

Comment: I got it, I think that "get in flap" can be replaced by "get nervous" too.

Answer (score 0):

"Get in a flap"  means become worried or excited or be agitated. It is an informal use.

> You shouldn't get in such a flap about things.